# Is this a suitable epsilon-delta proof of a limit?

Tags: limits

Fairly new to using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ proofs so could someone tell me if what I've got in the attached image is a suitable way to prove $$\lim_{x \to 0} 3x^3 = 0$$ Cheers

[image]

Comment: Yes is correct. But please try yo use latex >.<

Comment: Thanks, I know using LaTeX is better.. bit pushed for time and only spent a couple of hours learning it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks quite nice.  Two comments:

1. It's good practice to clearly separate the actual proof (the part that starts with "Take $\delta < ( \frac{\varepsilon}{3} )^{\frac{1}{3}}$.") from the calculations that lead to your choice of $\delta$.
2. The last inequality in your scratch work is backwards.  Specifically,
   $$
   |x| < \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} < \delta
   $$
   should read 
   $$
   |x| < \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \delta.
   $$
   The whole point (as you seem to understand) is that when $|x| < \delta$, then $x$ is close enough to $0$.  You can always make $\delta$ smaller and the proof will still be valid.  But, you cannot make $\delta$ bigger without potentially compromising the proof.